# Why did Hank Pym leave S.H.I.E.L.D?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

> In Ant Man, Hank Pym said that he stopped working for S.H.I.E.L.D. He expressed strong bitterness about it.

Why?

Note: This is not a spoiler because you learn all of it in the first few minutes of the movie. I am just keeping the warning as a courtesy.

Comment: Read the ant man prequel comics.

Comment: There's no point editing out the spoiler in the question if the title is the same spoiler. Even though it happens at the very start of the film, be considerate of people who haven't seen it. If anything, _as a courtesy_, you should leave the titled edited.

Comment: BTW: I think you don't really understand the meaning of spoiler... if you haven't seen *any part of the movie* yet, that kinda includes not seeing the first few minutes...

Comment: @CodeMed - To anyone who hasn't seen the movie, it is ALL a spoiler.

Answer (score 10):

In the same scene Hank comes in with a vial of their attempts at duplicating his formula. We can see he is very upset and that he is very protective of not wanting other people (not even this organization) to get the formula.

From the conversation it sounds like they have been trying to get it from him for a while and this is the last straw.

The bitterness was from the fact that they have been developing this behind his back.